# What is the range of the legacy IRQs supplied by the motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, irq

What is the range of the legacy IRQs supplied by the motherboard? Between what and what? One hard review for me.

1 to 15

0 to 14

0 to 15

1 to 8

Comment: Please at least _try_ to do a little of your own work: https://www.google.ca/search?q=irqs = http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_request which includes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_request#x86_IRQs

Comment: Asking a question doesn't mean I didn't do any of my work. If I we could all do research, we wouldn't need any Stack Exchange site, now would we? The whole reason I'm asking is because I need an answer I can rely on, rather than doing the research multiple times (which is the definition of insanity) and getting the same result. Even after, I still have the same exact questions left.

Comment: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @MikeWentworth, if you're doing research and you keep getting the same result, what about those results leads you to believe the results are incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source [Resolving Hardware Conflicts](http://www.blitter.com/~russtopia/MIDI/~jglatt/tutr/conflict.htm)

**Checking for conflicts**

> In order to unequivocally determine what IRQs, base addresses, and DMA
>   channels are in use on non-PnP devices, you need to know the
>   jumper/DIP settings of your cards.
>
> This includes all of your ISA cards as well as any non-PnP devices on
>   your motherboard. IRQ conflicts appear to be the biggest cause of
>   conflicts. Base address and DMA conflicts aren't nearly as common (but
>   if you have 2 or more of the same type of card in your system, for
>   example, 2 MIDI/audio cards, the chances of base and DMA conflicts
>   increase dramatically as many manufacturers of the same types of cards
>   follow each others' "standards" for IRQ/address/DMA settings. For
>   example, most MIDI cards use the Roland MPU-401 standard I/O address
>   of 330).
>
> Here's a list of what I've found to be the most common IRQ
>   assignments. I think that it's pretty safe to assume these, but beyond
>   the standard devices (ie, clocks, keyboard, serial + parallel ports,
>   HD and floppy controllers, math chip), check all of your other
>   devices:
>
> ```
> IRQ #
> 0      System timer
> 1      Keyboard
> 2      Cascade for second interrupt chip
> 3      Serial (COM) port 2 (often a modem is attached to this)
> 4      Serial (COM) port 1 (usually a serial mouse is attached to this)
> 5      Parallel port 2 (not often used)
> 6      Floppy controller
> 7      Parallel port 1 (usually a printer is attached to this)
> 8      Realtime clock
> 9      free (but some video cards may use this for EGA emulation)
> 10     free
> 11     free
> 12     free
> 13     Math chip
> 14     HD (IDE) controller
> 15     Second IDE controller (usually a CD-ROM is attached to this. This second
>        IDE controller may even be on your sound card, such as an SB card)
> ```
>
> Typically, sound cards are set to use IRQ 5. This is often a good
>   choice. Usually, IRQs 10, 11, and 12 are safe to use (assuming other
>   ISA cards aren't using such). If the card has a MPU-401 compatible
>   MIDI port, it usually uses I/O addresses 330 and 331 (hex). The MIDI
>   port may also use another IRQ such as 9, separate from the IRQ used by
>   the digital audio portion of the card.

***What is the range of the legacy IRQs supplied by the motherboard? Between what and what?**

Between 0 and 15

Comment: According to Wikipedia, newer systems using Intel APIC support 24 IRQs, the additional 8 IRQs are used to route PCI interrupts. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_request